# How to use php variable inside a javascript code in a php code?

Tags: javascript, php, echo, json

How can I implement this:

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "document.getElementById('table_apps').innerHTML = json_encode($td_temp);";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

There is a problem with $td_temp;

Comment: Have you set $td_temp with some text or something? You can use isset to check

Comment: Yes there is a string inside of the $td_temp to draw a table. I checked it. That's OK.

Comment: It's also because json_encode is a php function, so you need to remove it from the string eg. " . json_encode

Comment: I've added an answer that I think you'll find useful from an informational/learning perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode()` is a PHP function

Do like this

```
echo "document.getElementById('table_apps').innerHTML ='".json_encode($td_temp)."';";
```

Comment: innerHTML should be wrapped in single quotes as well as escaping any single quotes in the json data.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: '".json_encode($td_temp)."' - it's wrong no need for single qoutes

Comment: @SpongeBob author you should better use my example, believe me i know what i'm talking about

Comment: @Alex, I don't agree, if anything your answer was originally wrong and is still incomplete. You don't encapsulate the encoded json string in quotes, nor escape it. This was accepted as correct because it did at least encapsulate the string which is at least 50% correct. The next best answer was provided by Satish because he provided two clear examples of generating PHP with HTML.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this without echo

```
<?php

// some code

?>
       <script type='text/javascript'>
          document.getElementById('table_apps').innerHTML = '<?php echo json_encode($td_temp);?>';
       </script>

<?php

// some code

?>
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "document.getElementById('table_apps').innerHTML = '".json_encode($td_temp)."';";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Escape the json for single quotes and this answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

You should better print not all this html from php, but only a variable. Looks  more neat

```
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('table_apps').innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($td_temp); ?>;
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong and you have <?php echo encapsulated in a string

Comment: @Justin Mitchell you sure? check it, it's not wrong

Comment: Thanks but I want it in php.

Comment: You updated while I was posting my first comment. Also, you need to escape the json and surround it in single quotes.

Comment: no i don't need, check it, single quotes adds automatically echo json_encode("sfhafdh");

Comment: You do realise that if you were to add a single quote, an escaping character or a terminating character, your script would break, right?

Comment: give me example of that and i'll check it

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "document.getElementById('table_apps').innerHTML = '".json_encode($td_temp)."';";
        echo "</script>";
    ?>
Try this.
```

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't work. Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: That's because the string wasn't quoted or escaped

Comment: And because json_encode is still encapsulated **inside** or a php string and will be interpreted **literally**

Comment: but down voting really discourage a developer's strength. :(

Answer (score -1):

It's vitally important to:

1. encapsulate the encoded json string in quotes
2. escape any encoded json string

Why?

Because if you were to provide an array of names for example, and you had O'Connell or any other name that has a quotation mark in it, then the `innerHTML = '<?php echo json_encode...'` would break because of an un-escaped quotation mark. It's important to practise proper encapsulation and validation as much as possible because it future proofs any application you develop, reduces points of failure, or in the case of try/catch/exception, clearly defines intended points of failure.

What happens if you were to create a json object that had a semi-colon in the content? Unless you're wrapping your json content in single quotes and correctly escaping it, it might be interpreted literally as the termination of the current command. So when you try to enter `.innerHTML='{blah:"something O'Connel;...}'`, your Javascript will throw an error because of bad formatting, not to mention it can't interpret 'Connel' before the terminating character. Some browsers are more slack that others (IE I'm looking at you) and will either skip validation or perform a sub-standard routine, or in the case of IE6-8, perform the wrong validation.

There have been mostly correct and incorrect answers so far, but so far all answers have neglected to do one thing, escape quotes:

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "document.getElementById('table_apps').innerHTML = '" . addslashes(json_encode($td_temp)) . "';";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

That will correctly:

1. Escape quotes, and
2. Generate a json-encoded object

Comment: s"o/me\_s\tr
var a = "s\"o\/me\\_s\\tr";
var b = '\"s\\\"o\\/me\\\\_s\\\\tr\"';
the second is your string. check it in firebug console it's not working

Comment: PHP Console:
`php > $a = array("apples" => "o'connel");
php > print json_encode($a);
{"apples":"o'connel"}` Notice how it doesn't add slashes? You can also be selective about the addslashes function, I suggest you read up on it. How do I know? Well, it's because I've developed a number of REST applications and ajax driven web applications using JSON as the message content service.